# Population growth equation

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics, simulations

I'm at the very early stages of designing a game in which the population increases / decreases according to other factors (eg. crop yield / food scarcity, industrialization, global warming?, wars, natural disasters / diseases, etc). I'm not a mathematician so I'm searching for equations that might help me incorporate some or all of the above factors.

The number of factors that affect the equation can be limited so as to make the equation easier.

Are other equations that might suit my needs better?

Comment: Have you considered researching games that include similar mechanics, say 4X games like Civ, and examining how they implement it? Try editing your question to narrow down what would separate a good equation for your needs from a bad one, to focus answers on solving a specific problem rather than an open-ended grab bag of possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with looking at the Lotke-Voltera equations ([https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka–Volterra_equations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations)). They can be easily adapted to multiple resources and you can  always add fast changing terms for natural desasters and such.

Also make sure to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World3. This is a model used for trying to predict the real population growth if the earth.

Comment: This answer relies a lot on information provided by Wikipedia. It is possible that the above links break in the future. For that reason it might be better to add the relevant key points of those articles to the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method of modeling population growth in a game is to multiply the current population a set amount per step. You can change the growth factor based on available resources and active constraints. The population also determines resource production and consumption per step.

You might also want to separate birth rate and death rate; the birth rate mostly remains static unless cultural changes come into play, while the death rate is more subject to things like diseases, war, etc.

Depending on the timescales involved and how accurate you need it to be, you might also want to track demographics; creating new people at age 0 and storing the population for each age as a separate value in an array. You can modify the birth, death, and resource production/consumption rates based on ages. Young adults are more likely to produce children and old people are more likely to die as they age; prior to modern medicine infant mortality was also much higher, you can account for this by lowering "effective" birth rates for pre-modern civilizations or increasing death among children.

Factoring in demographics will make your program significantly more complicated (and slow) so you might want to avoid this. A lot of games only really take working-age population into account and abstract the child/elderly population as a percentage of that.